# Separate the controllers in a new project? Is this a good design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

My colleague told me to separate my controllers in a separate project to make the unit testing as easy as possible, and he also told me to create a solution for the controllers project and test project to avoid loading the whole application when conducting unit testing. Is it a good approach to separate the controllers in a new project?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a simple yes or no answer to this question. I would think that your project would have to be very, very large as to have impact on your unit testing. My *personal opinion* is to leave the controllers in the web project along with the views and view models. However, I am a fan of moving the models to a separate project. My reasons for doing so have less to do with easier unit testing but rather reusing the data access (models) in other applications.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should always at least separate the controllers from your view project (usually a web project for me), because the idea is that the controllers should be able to be used with any view (maybe later you decide to use them for a Windows Forms project, for example). It keeps the namespaces a bit cleaner as well.

Comment: Kad81, actually that is also what I am thinking, I searched the web to get a tutorials on how to do this one, but I failed, there are some, but it's hard to understand. I hope you can send me some links regarding this approach. :)

Comment: I see that you are using ASP.NET MVC... sorry I don't actually have much experience using that specific framework. I agree that good examples are hard to come by for it. My general advice in this case would be to consider the size of the application and the need for re-usability of components such as controllers. If it's likely to be a fairly small, self-contained web system, then it probably won't make much difference where you put them. You can always move stuff later, too (although sometimes with a bit of pain involved).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good idea at first. Creating a prensentation layer in the middle and keeping your MVC project containing only views, making it truly a UI project. On the other hand, you will probably lose the tooling support for the views. Since you have to ignore all the warnings, you have to make sure all views are there, strongly typed to your object.

I don't understand the concern for referencing your MVC project in your test suite since you will probably bring in the MVC namespace anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, making you move out the controllers to a separate project has two things to consider, if you do so, then it enforces you to think how to solve problems with low coupling and precisely low coupled classes can be tested more easily than tight coupled classes.

On the other hand, having the controllers in the same project than the views is kind of logical because the controllers normally know about the views.

If you think of reusability there may be something arguable here because often controllers are "glue" components this means, there is a lot of wiring in them.

Comment: I agree with you, and I think there's a lot to work to do specially wiring them up into the view. I am new in MVC, so for me it very confusing in terms of making a good architecture using this technology.

Comment: To put MVC in simple words, Views are generic, they are your "components" and you should be able to use them where you please, controllers listen to what happens in views and update the model, also they query the model to display it on the views.

Comment: You are correct in saying that the controller knows about the view. The key is, however, that the controller only needs to know about the view interface, not about the view itself. My design always puts controllers in the same assembly as the view interfaces, and then my web project implements those interfaces. In this way, you can unit test the control logic by creating simple classes to emulate the web pages by implementing the view interfaces.